# What's a better option: Half Rounded or k-style gutters?

Tags: gutters

I've been going back and forth about gutters, what size, style and cover I should buy. I recently saw rounded gutters and loved the look. But are they better?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. My guess is that any answer would be too opinion-based for our site, but let's see what others think.

Comment: The water doesn't care. Unless you define what would qualify as "better" here, the question is vague and subjective. Feel free to revise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can get extremely specific to how much water each holds, if that is a concern, but that also brings the size of the gutter into play, which can be changed to accommodate your needs.

They're both installed similar ways, easy to work with, so neither is better in any way, it is certainly only a matter of what you think looks better for your application.